# XML to XML Transformation with different Inner nodes but with same outer nodes using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have started learning XSLT

When I am working on that I getting an wrong type of XML Format
    Input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<root>
  <test>
    <access1>113AL</access1>
    <access2>119AL</access2>
  </test>
  <test>
    <access2>115AL</access2>
    <access3>116AL</access3>
  </test>
  <test>
    <access4>118AL</access4>
    <access5>119AL</access5>
  </test>
  <copies>
    <test2>
      <a>113AL</a>
      <Copy1>Y</Copy1>
    </test2>
    <test2>
      <a>113AX</a>
      <Copy1>N</Copy1>
    </test2>
  </copies>
</root>
```

Expected Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<root>
  <test>
    <access1>113AL</access1>
    <Indicator>true</Indicator>
    <Copy>Y</Copy>
    <access2>119AL</access2>
  </test>
  <test>
    <access2>115AL</access2>
    <access3>116AL</access3>
  </test>
  <test>
    <access4>118AL</access4>
    <access5>119AL</access5>
  </test>
</root>
```

I am trying to compare root/test/access values with root/test/access . If a match is found, it should include the corresponding Copy tag.
My XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<root>
<xsl:for-each select="test">
<test>
<access1><xsl:value-of select="//access1"/></access1>
<access2><xsl:value-of select="//access2"/></access2>
<xsl:for-each select="root/copies/test2/access">
<xsl:if test ="access1=test2/access">
<Copy>Y</Copy>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</test>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:for-each select="test">
<test>
<access2><xsl:value-of select="//access2"/></access2>
<access3><xsl:value-of select="//access3"/></access3>
<xsl:for-each select="root/copies/test2/access">
<xsl:if test ="access1=test2/access">
<Copy>Y</Copy>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</test>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:for-each select="test">
<test>
<access4><xsl:value-of select="//access4"/></access4>
<access5><xsl:value-of select="//access5"/></access5>
<xsl:for-each select="root/copies/test2/access">
<xsl:if test ="access1=test2/access">
<Copy>Y</Copy>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</test>
</xsl:for-each>
</root>
```

This gives me wrong output. Can any one help me here where I am making a mistake and please help me with how to do it in XSLT 1.0?

Comment: Is the section labeled "Output" what you _want_, or is it the incorrect output your are currently seeing?  If it is the incorrect output, please provide the expected output.

Comment: section labeled output is the expected output.

Comment: There's not enough information to answer.  Where did `access6` and `access8` come from? What rule resulted in `access8` having that text?

Comment: sorry it's a typo mistake...

Comment: I have edited it... could you please have a look ..

Comment: `<access1>113AL</access-panel>` is not valid XML and cannot be processed by an XSLT transformer.

Comment: Why are there two XML headers on the expected output? Do you really want two?

Comment: even after editing I am not getting expected output

Comment: yeah..I need two headers

Comment: That is not valid XML either.  You can't make an XSLT processor do that.  Other than the double headers your question is now asking for the [Identity Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) where the output is identical to the input.

Comment: edited the requirement code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This whole question is a little bit confusing.
The **input xml** is still not valide: I use this fixed version :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root>
        <test>
            <access1>113AL</access1>
            <access2>119AL</access2>
        </test>
        <test>
            <access2>115AL</access2>
            <access3>116AL</access3>
        </test>
        <test>
            <access4>118AL</access4>
            <access5>119AL</access5>
        </test>
        <copies>
            <test2>
                <access>113AL</access>
                <Copy>Y</Copy>
            </test2>
            <test2>
                <access>113AX</access>
                <Copy>N</Copy>
            </test2>
            </copies>
    </root>
```

Also

> I am trying to compare root/test/access values with root/test/access . If a match is found, it should include the corresponding Copy tag.

It seems this should be compare root/test/access values with **root/copies/test2/access**

Therefore you may try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="test">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            <xsl:variable name="thisaccess" select="*[starts-with(name(), 'access')]" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//copies/test2[access=$thisaccess]/Copy" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="copies"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With the following output:

```
        <root>
            <test>
                <access1>113AL</access1>
                <access2>119AL</access2>
                <Copy>Y</Copy>
            </test>
            <test>
                <access2>115AL</access2>
                <access3>116AL</access3>
            </test>
            <test>
                <access4>118AL</access4>
                <access5>119AL</access5>
            </test>
        </root>
```

Update: Due to comment.

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="test/*[starts-with(name(), 'access')]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:variable name="thisaccess" select="." />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//copies/test2[access=$thisaccess]/Copy" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="copies"/>
```

And the new output:

```
<root>
    <test>
        <access1>113AL</access1>
        <Copy>Y</Copy>
        <access2>119AL</access2>
    </test>
    <test>
        <access2>115AL</access2>
        <access3>116AL</access3>
    </test>
    <test>
        <access4>118AL</access4>
        <access5>119AL</access5>
    </test>
 </root>
```

Comment: [Fatal Error] NewFile.xml:1:9: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.

Comment: Hm there is no  processing instruction in above xml or xslt . Only the xml declaration  `<?xml version="1.0" ...`. This need to be in the first line an the first pos of the xml file .

Comment: You are talking about the change in input? I do not see any change in expected  output.

Comment: input remains the same...The order of tags is changed in the expected output. <Copy>Y</Copy> tag should appear in the middle instead at the end...

Answer (score 0):

Your XSLT transform file look quite strange, have a look to tutorial in order to have a better feeling how XSLT works, for eaxmple: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp .

for your case, I propose you the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="root">
        <xsl:apply-templates name="copyTest" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="copyTest" match="root">
    <xsl:copy-of select="test"></xsl:copy-of>
</xsl:template>
```

That copies the `test` elements directly under the element `root` but not the ones under the element `Copies`

Comment: I do not really understand your need. For formatting purpose or bulk transformation, XSLT can be relevant. For more exotic purpose, it would certainly easier for you to use implement your logic in java, and use JaxB for the java binding ("read and write" the XML elements from/to Java objects).

Comment: As I said earlier, I am new to XSLT and I am just experimenting with the code from Internet...

Comment: Is it possible? certainly. Does it make sense? or is an other technology more adapted?  If you are new to XSLT, FIRST start with good tutorials (like from W3School) and then it is good to test you on your own challenges (as you try now).